# How to estimate mean and variance of a normal distribution given the numbers?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Given the numbers generated in a normal distribution:
$5.3299, 4.2537, 3.1502, 3.7032, 1.6070, 6.3923, 3.1181, 6.5941, 3.5281, 4.7433, 0.1077, 1.5977, 5.4920, 1.7220, 4.1547, 2.2799$

How would I guess an estimate for $μ$ and $σ^2$? I believe $μ$ would just be the average of the values, but how can I find the average?

Comment: Is [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters?) what you're looking for ?

Comment: Where does the unbiased estimator formula come from? (of the variance)

Comment: If you use $\frac1n$ as you might think natural, and take the expected value, you will find it is off by a factor of $\frac{n}{n-1}$. This corrects the problem. This link http://isites.harvard.edu/fs/docs/icb.topic515975.files/Proof%20that%20Sample%20Variance%20is%20Unbiased.pdf has a detailed explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the standard estimators to estimate the mean and variance for any distribution from a collection $\{X_k\}$ of samples. $$\bar X = \frac1n\sum_{k=1}^n X_k$$
and $$s^2 = \frac1{n-1}\sum_{k=1}^n(X_k-\bar X)^2$$
These are both unbiased.